# Autocomplete Google Place API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-autocomplete

I am facing a problem when using Google Place API with Auto complete. I want to restrict the search to Greece and in iOS it is working [Screenshot iOS](https://prnt.sc/pkky3e)  but in Android it returns data in German [Screenshot Android](https://prnt.sc/pkkvm9).
Below is the Autocompleted API method with values

```
Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).setCountry("GR").build(context);
```

Comment: "Karaiskaki 70, Agia Paraskevi, Griechenland" is a Greek location. Are you actually referring to Autocomplete results being displayed in German language instead of Greek in Android? If so, what is the language of your Android device?

Comment: Please see my answer in related thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/58486817/11742502

Comment: @Evan thanks for the reply, our device language is english